# Square brackets notation inside object definition

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript we can access or create Object properties dynamically by using `[]`. Is it documented that one also can use it while defining/creating the object?

As far as I tested (Chrome, FF, Safari) latest versions this works good. Is this documented, did old browsers also support this?

```
var key = "foo";
var value = 'bar';
var object = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    [key]: value,
    c: 3
};

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(object); // {"a":1,"b":2,"foo":"bar","c":3}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o2x6chzd/

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility or http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_computed_properties for browser support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's called a computed property name and is new in ES2015.

It means you can add object properties with runtime-chosen names in the same lexical construction as the object instance creation.

Previously you had to add properties with runtime-computed names after object instantiation.

Expressions can be used to compute the name:

```
function foo() { return 1; }
var o = {
  [foo() + 1]: 'should be 2'
};
console.log(o); // Object {2: "should be 2"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with ECMAScript 6, the object initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets [], that will be computed as the property name.

Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Comment: It's no longer called ECMAScript 6.

Comment: 2015 is the approval date, the edition is 6, so technically speaking they are the same..

Comment: It is indeed edition 6 of ECMAScript, but the name of the language is "ECMAScript 2015".